# trying to Azure AD authentication with gRPC-Web using protobuf-net

Tags: asp.net-core, protobuf-net, blazor-webassembly, protobuf-net.grpc

I am trying to Azure AD authentication with gRPC-Web in a blazor webassembly app. I am using protobuf-net to help me with the serialization. I am not sure how to pass the token to have the server side recognize it. this is what I have:

```
var headers = new Metadata
               {
                 { "Authorization", $"Bearer {Token}" }
               };
```

and, I am sending that as a parameter in the method I want to consume

```
var result = await Client.CreateCustomer(this.customer, headers);
```

This is how the service is injected:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(services =>
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
            var channel = Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress("****", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
            return channel.CreateGrpcService<Application.Services.ICustomerService<ServerCallContext>>();
        });
```

This is how the service is published:

```
endpoints.MapGrpcService<CustomerService>().RequireAuthorization().EnableGrpcWeb()
```

and, this is the implementation:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService<ServerCallContext>
{
    [Authorize]
    public async ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO, ServerCallContext context) 
    {****}
}
```

the error I am getting is cannot convert from 'Grpc.Core.Metadata' to 'Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext' which is kind of obvious.

The reference I have found uses Metadata but is ServerCallContext the one I am supposed to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/metadata  so what I am missing, what I am doing wrong, how to properly use both using protobuf-net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that you're using `ServerCallContext` in the method signature; the underlying gRPC core has separate client/server context APIs, but this is not amenable to use on an agnostic interface, and as such, protobuf-net.Grpc *unifies* these two APIs, via `CallContext`. So: instead of:

```cs
async ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO, ServerCallContext context)
```

for the signature, consider:

```cs
async ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO, CallContext context)
```

or

```cs
async ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO, CallContext context = default)
```

---

The `CallContext` API exposes the common server-side and client-side APIs (headers, cancellation, etc) in a single way, or you can use (for example) `context.ServerCallContext` to get the server-specific API if needed (this will throw an exception if used on a client-context). For client-side usage, a `CallContext` can be constructed from a `CallOptions`, which is the core gRPC client-side API, for example:

```cs
var result = await service.CreateCustomer(customer, new CallOptions(headers));
```

---

I'm *open* to the idea of allowing `CallContext` to be created directly from `Metadata` / `CancellationToken` etc (allowing `var result = await service.CreateCustomer(customer, headers);`) - but it doesn't seem *essential*.

Comment: @paburgos you're welcome; if it answered your question, please consider pressing that green tick icon